# Insert a space after every given character - java

Tags: java, regex

I need to insert a space after every given character in a string.

For example `"abc.def..."`

Needs to become `"abc. def. . . "`

So in this case the given character is the dot.

My search on google brought no answer to that question

I really should go and get some serious regex knowledge.

EDIT : ----------------------------------------------------------

```
String test = "0:;1:;";
test.replaceAll( "\\:", ": " );
System.out.println(test);

// output: 0:;1:;
// so didnt do anything
```

SOLUTION: -------------------------------------------------------

```
String test = "0:;1:;";
**test =** test.replaceAll( "\\:", ": " );
System.out.println(test);
```

Comment: you need to use string.replace(".",". ")

Comment: replaceAll() takes a regex as first parameter. ":" has no special meaning inside a regex, so you don't have to escape it. After removing the double backslashes, your code should work fine.

Comment: @tangens no it sadly doesnt

Comment: You have to use the result of String.replaceAll(). Strings are immutable in java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String input = "abc.def...";
String result = input.replaceAll( "\\.", ". " );
// result will be "abc. def. . . "
```

Edit:

```
String test = "0:;1:;";
result = test.replaceAll( ":", ": " );
// result will be "0: ;1: ;" (test is still unmodified)
```

Edit:

As said in other answers, `String.replace()` is all you need for this simple substitution. Only if it's a regular expression (like you said in your question), you have to use `String.replaceAll()`.

Comment: No, this doesn't quite fit what the OP wants.  He/she wants to be able to do this for ANY character, not just for dot.  With this solution, some characters will need the preceding backslash and some won't.  You'll need to use `Pattern.quote` if you want to do the replacement with `replaceAll`, and this will sort out whether the character needs quoting.  For this particular problem though, it's much easier just to use `replace`, not `replaceAll`.

Comment: @DavidWallace could you please post an more detailed answer

Comment: @DavidWallace for now, at least so that it works with the ":"

Comment: My comment under 2570707's answer tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: What doesn't work?  Using `replace` works fine for me.

Comment: @DavidWallace i changed it to " test.replace(":", ": "); ", but still no space after the ":"

Comment: @DavidWallace sorry, my bad, it works... i didnt assign it to the old string but just ran the operation

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace.

```
text = text.replace(".", ". ");
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: This is the best answer.  Of course, in the general case, it would be `text.replace(targetCharacter, targetCharacter + " ");` where `targetCharacter` is a `String`, equal to the character that is sought.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple brute force technique. The following code will do it.

```
String input = "abc.def...";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    char c = input.getCharAt(i);
    output.append(c);
    output.append(" ");
}
return output.toString();
```